# Is there a way to find out which process is setting a Linux kernel parameter to an invalid value at runtime?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, kubernetes

I have set the kernel parameter fs.inotify.max_user_instances to 100000000, but it is automatically getting set to 1256 after a while. Is there some way to figure out which process is setting it to 1256 ?
I am setting the parameter like this :

```
$ tail /etc/sysctl.conf
<snip>

fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 100000000
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 100000000

$ sysctl -p
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 100000000
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 100000000
```

After a while, I can see that it has been set to 1256

```
$ sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 1256
```

This is a Kubernetes worker node running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

Comment: My guess is that it may well be the kernel itself that resets the number to a sane value. A hundred million is quite a large number, since each watcher consumes about 1 kB of kernel memory each, which adds up to 100 GB of RAM.